# LaTeX3 floating point sqrt() doesn't seem to work when ^ or ** is used on negative operands

Tags: expl3, latex3

I'm working on a parser to calculate a vector's magnitude and it seems the sqrt() function throws an error when acting on an expression containing the ^ or ** operator operating on a negative number. Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \l_my_parsevector #1 #2 {%
  \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { #2 } % copy the vector to a clist
  \clist_pop:NN \l_tmpa_clist {\x}   % get the leftmost item
  %\fp_zero_new:c { l__#1_fp }        % new fp variable
  \fp_set:cn { l__#1_fp } {\x}       % assign it the first component
  %[\x]
  \clist_pop:NN \l_tmpa_clist {\y}   % get the leftmost item
  %\fp_zero_new:c { l__#1_fp }        % new fp variable
  \fp_set:cn { l__#1_fp } {\y}       % assign it the second component
  %[\y]
  \clist_pop:NN \l_tmpa_clist {\z}   % get the leftmost item
  %\fp_zero_new:c { l__#1_fp }        % new fp variable
  \fp_set:cn { l__#1_fp } {\z}       % assign it the third component
  %[\z]
}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\VectorMagnitude}{ O{a} m }{%
  \l_my_parsevector{#1}{#2}
  %\fp_eval:n { sqrt(\x*\x+\y*\y+\z*\z) } % always gives correct result
  \fp_eval:n { sqrt(\x^2+\y^2+\z^2) }     % Invalid operation sqrt(-16)
}%
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\VectorMagnitude{0,-4,0}
\end{document}
```

Page 213 of the current `interface3` documentation seems to indicate this is the intended behavior but it's confusingly stated. Is there a reason this syntax doesn't work? I note that changing -4 to 4 gives correct results in both cases.

Comment: Probably because if `\x` is `-4` then it expands to `-4^2` which is interpreted as `-(4^2)`. It's safer to add parentesis...

Comment: Thank you. I think I tried every use of parentheses except that one.

Comment: Most languages / tools evaluate -4^2 (or -4**2) as negative 16. Microsoft's Excel is about the only language / tool that evaluates -4^2 as positive 16.

Comment: Yes I should have recognized that. Every time I think I see a parallel between LaTeX3 and other programming languages I'm shown it's wrong so I don't always trust myself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should do `(\x)^2` to protect the possible minus sign. Without the parentheses you get `-4^2` which is correctly evaluated as `-16`.

On the other hand, you can do much better:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\VectorMagnitude}{O{15}m}
 {
  \fp_eval:n
   {
    round ( sqrt( 0 \clist_map_function:nN { #2 } \latexerexetal_square:n ) , #1 )
   }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \latexerexetal_square:n { + (#1)^2 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\VectorMagnitude{0,-4,0}

\VectorMagnitude{1,1,1}

\VectorMagnitude{3,4,0}

\VectorMagnitude[4]{3,4,0,-1,3,pi}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The command is fully expandable; for instance

```
\edef\test{\VectorMagnitude[4]{3,4,0,-1,3,pi}}
```

would result in `\test` having `6.6985` as replacement text.

---

Some notes on your code. A function name should not start with `l_`, which is reserved to variables. It should also have a signature for the arguments, so your `\l_my_parsevector` should actually be

```
\my_parsevector:nn
```

and should be defined with `\cs_new_protected:Npn`, because it does assignments.

Also `\clist_pop_left:NN` should be followed by a clist variable and a tl variable, both unbraced; `\x` is not to be used as the name of a `tl` variable.

If you want to extract the third, say, item in a clist variable and set to it an fp variable, it's simpler to say

```
\fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { 3 } }
```

instead of popping the items one after the other. But the method I suggested is much simpler.

With `\clist_map_function:nN { #1 } \latexerexetal_square:n` we get in one swoop

```
\latexerexetal_square:n { 0 } \latexerexetal_square:n { -4 } \latexerexetal_square:n { 0 }
```

and at the next stages of expansion this becomes

```
+ (0)^2 + (-4)^2 + (0)^2
```

The initial `0` is still in front of everything (it's not really necessary, actually); so the expression is correctly evaluated.

Since everything used is fully expandable, I could define `\VectorMagnitude` with `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`. The optional argument is the number of digits for rounding.

Comment: Thank you. I understand my LaTeX3 code is unacceptable at this point because I'm still learning it. I don't yet understand mapping but hopefully this concrete example will get the point across.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL I added a comment with some explanations of the action.

Comment: BTW, I would happily volunteer to work on documenting some of this stuff with concrete examples. My background is physics and I could supply concrete and relevant examples.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL I'm currently writing some documentation for `fp` evaluations. You can easily find my email address from my profile.